# Query jobs with more than one vendor

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to list all job info for jobs that have purchase orders (pos) for more than one vendor
Here are the columns in the two tables

```
table pos
+--------+-------+------------+
| job_id | po_id |   vendor   |
+--------+-------+------------+

table jobs

+--------+---------+---------+
| job_id | cust_id | jobtype |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

I'm currently at a loss as to how i can use a subquery to return those jobs that are listed with more than 1 vendor. Any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT*** >>>>

```
mysql> select j.*, vendor, count(vendor) as count 
from jobs j join pos p on p.job_id=j.job_id 
group by vendor 
having count(vendor) > 0;
```

This query returns almost correct results, except that it shows the same job_id twice in the table, when instead of the duplicate, i want only distinct job_id's to show. trying to use distinct with job_id returns 'column job_id is ambiguous'
Is it a matter of group by? Do i need a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE job_id IN (
  SELECT
  job_id
  FROM
  pos
  GROUP BY job_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT vendor) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select job_id
from pos p
group by job_id
having count(distinct vendor) > 0
```

I see, you want all job info:

```
select j.*
from job j
where job_id in (select p.job_id
                 from pos p
                 group by p.job_id
                 having count(distinct p.vendor) > 0
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps are:

1. Join the tables using `job_id` (`INNER JOIN`)
2. Count the PO vendors associated with each job record (`COUNT(DISTINCT pos.vendor)`)
3. Include only those jobs that have more than one PO vendor (`HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT pos.vendor) > 1`)

   ```
   SELECT job_id, cust_id, jobtype, COUNT(DISTINCT pos.vendor)
     FROM jobs
     INNER JOIN pos ON jobs.job_id = pos.job_id
     GROUP BY job_id, cust_id, jobtype
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pos.vendor) > 1
   ```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I realized that as soon as I posted - it was a case of misunderstanding the question at first read. I was editing my answer as you posted the comment.  The updated answer should be fine, or at least it does what I *think* the question asks :) Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing something. What part of the brief does the following query not satisfy?

```
SELECT j.* 
  FROM jobs j 
  JOIN pos p 
    ON p.job_id = j.job_id 
 GROUP 
    BY j.job_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```